# CUDA kernels and memory access (one kernel doesn't execute entirely and the next doesn't get launched)

Tags: memory, cuda

I'm having trouble here. I launch two kernels , check if some value is the one expected (memcpy to the host), if it is I stop, if it isn't I launch the two kernels again.

the first kernel:

```
__global__  void aco_step(const KPDeviceData* data)
{
int obj = threadIdx.x;
int ant = blockIdx.x;
int id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

*(data->added) = 1;

while(*(data->added) == 1)
{
    *(data->added) = 0;

    //check if obj fits
    int fits = (data->obj_weights[obj] + data->weight[ant] <= data->max_weight);
    fits = fits * !(getElement(data->selections, data->selections_pitch, ant, obj));

    if(obj == 0)
        printf("ant %d going..\n", ant);
    __syncthreads();

...
```

The code goes on after this. But that printf never gets printed, that syncthreads is there just for debugging purposes.

The "added" variable was shared, but since shared memory is a PITA and usually throws bugs in the code, i just removed it for now. This "added" variable isn't the smartest thing to do but it's faster than the alternative, which is checking if any variable within an array is some value on the host and deciding to keep iterating or not.

The getElement, simply does the matrix memory calculation with the pitch to access the right position and returns the element there:

```
int* el = (int*) ((char*)mat + row * pitch) + col;
return *el;
```

The obj_weights array has the right size, n*sizeof(int). So does the weight array, ants*sizeof(float). So they aren't out of bounds.

The kernel after this one has a printf right on the beginning, and it doesn't get printed either and after the printf it sets a variable on the device memory, and this memory is copied to the CPU after the kernel finished, and it isn't the right value when I print it in the CPU code. So I think this kernel is doing something illegal and the second one doesn't even get launched.

I'm testing some instances, when I launch 8 blocks and 512 threads, it runs OK. 32 blocks, 512 threads, OK. But 8 blocks and 1024 threads, and this happens, the kernel doesn't work, neither 32 blocks and 1024 threads.

Am I doing something wrong? Memory access? Am I launching too many threads?

**edit**: tried removing the "added" variable and the while loop, so it should execute just once. Still doesnt work, nothing gets printed, even if the printf is right after the three initial lines and the next kernel also doesn't print anything.

**edit**: another thing, I'm using a GTX 570, so the  "Maximum number of threads per block" is 1024 according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA. Maybe I'll just stick with 512 maximum or check on how higher I can put this value.

Answer (score 3):

`__syncthreads()` inside conditional code is only allowed if the condition evaluates identically on all threads of a block.

In your case the condition suffers a race condition and is nondeterministic, so it most probably evaluates to different results for different threads.

`printf()` output is only displayed after the kernel finishes successfully. In this case it doesn't due to the problem mentioned above, so the output never shows up. You could have figured out this by testing the return codes all CUDA function calls for errors.

Comment: Alright, I got that syncthreads point, completely forgot about it. But about the memory writes, if multiple threads write to the same address the same value, the value will be updated, what is unknown is how many times it will be updated. Taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953955/concurrent-writes-in-the-same-global-memory-location

Comment: Upvoted because i didn't know kernel launches returned errors, so i'm close the finding the problem. Got the error catching code here:  http://code.google.com/p/stanford-cs193g-sp2010/wiki/TutorialWhenSomethingGoesWrong

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the *(data->added) test is meant to do. But to at least remove the race condition, insert a __syncthreads() before the while(). Since __syncthreads() synchronizes per-block, this would also require to move the flag back to shared memory (don't be afraid of it - there is nothing wrong with shared memory if programmed correctly).

Comment: I was using dinamically allocated shared arrays and all they did was bug up my code. I moved the added Variable back to shared, it works now. I also changed the code a bit. Launching 512 threads per block is fine, but apparently launching 1024 isn't, even with my GPU supporting 1024 per block.

Comment: A shortage of some other ressources (i.e. registers or shared memory) may prevent you from launching the maximum supported number of threads per block. You can use the Occupancy Calculator spreadsheet from Nvidia to check the limit for your specific case.