# Is it safe that two threads write a same value into a same global memory variable without any locks or synchronizations?

Tags: cuda

Is it safe that two threads write a same value into a same global memory variable without any locks or synchronizations ?

Will the result always be determinate and right?

How about shared memory variable and register variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a similar question (with answer) here:
[Concurrent writes in the same global memory location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953955/concurrent-writes-in-the-same-global-memory-location)

In general, the paralleled programmatic models there are not guarantees of the order of execution between several threads. So you are going to have different behavior in each program execution.

Comment: But the two answers from Tom and talonmies are totally opposite. Which is right? Though talonmies' answer was accepted, @Tom's is much newer than talonmies and introduces more references.

Comment: Tom is correct there - on compute capability 2.0 or higher one of the writes will succeed, but which one is undefined. The same is true for shared memory on all compute capabilities (assuming the accesses are naturally aligned, which is always required anyway). Register variables are thread-private, so a conflict can never occur there.

Comment: About the Tom answer: he says that it is ok if all the threads write the **same valor** at the **same address**. Which is a very special case.
The problem here is guess which thread made the **last** write.